# Algorithm and code in SCILAB for row reduced echelon form

Tags: algorithm, scilab

I am a novice learner of SCILAB, and I know that there is a pre-defined function rref to produce the row reduced echelon form. I am looking for an algorithm for transforming a m x n matrix into row reduced echelon form and normal form and hence find the rank of a matrix.

Can you please help? Also, we have rref as a pre-defined function in SCILAB, how can we get the scilab code for it? How to find out the code/ algorithm  behind any function in SCILAB?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

### Help about functions

The help pages of Scilab always provide some information and short examples. You can also look at the help online ([rref help](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.0/en_US/rref.html)).

The examples are without output, but demonstrate the various uses. A good first approach is to copy-paste the complete example code into a new scinotes window, save it and press `F5` to see what it does. Then modify or extend the code to suite your wanted behavior.

### rref & rank

Aren't you looking for the [rank](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.0/en_US/rank.html) function instead? Here an example of using both.

```
A = [1,2,3;4,5,6;1,2,3]

rref(A);
rank(A);

B = [1,2,3;7,5,6;0,8,7];
rref(B);
rank(B);
```

### Source code

Since Scilab is open source you can find the source code on [their git repository](http://gitweb.scilab.org/?p=scilab.git;a=summary), for instance the rref implementation is [here](http://gitweb.scilab.org/?p=scilab.git;a=blob;f=scilab/modules/linear_algebra/macros/rref.sci).